# Series expansion error in a hypergeometric function

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion, maple

**Bug introduced in 5.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.2**

---

Compared to the Maple 2016 result of the series expansion around $x=0$ of ${}_2F_1(1,1;-1/3;1-x)$ up to order 3, *Mathematica* 11.1 seems to return an incorrect result. I may be wrong so could someone please check the details?

The thing is both could be wrong, although below I compared them to the exact evaluation, and the Maple solution is closer to the result of an exact computation.

According to the [Maple 2016 online document](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/new_features/maple2016/advancedmath.pdf)
[image: Maple example]

Looks like the marked term is missing in the *Mathematica* solution, as presented below:

```
f[x_] = Normal[FullSimplify[Series[Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, -(1/3), 1 - x], {x, 0, 3}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica result]

Comparing *Mathematica* (f, blue) and Maple (g, yellow), Maple gives better approx. so it could be correct:

```
g[x_] := f[x] - 64/6561 π Sqrt[3] x^(8/3) 
errf[x_] := f[x] - Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, -1/3, 1 - x];
errg[x_] := g[x] - Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, -1/3, 1 - x];
Plot[{errf[x], errg[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot]

This is not a proof, but just an indication. Could someone please look at the details and "formally" conclude if just one of them wrong, or both, and what is going on?

Comment: This seems more like an answer than a question.  You should report errors/ bugs to Wolfram. (Menu Help > Give Feedback...)

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Reported as a bug.

Comment: Looks like this one has been around since version 5.2.

Answer (score 4):

It's present for me:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, this one is missing the `11/3` power.  I'm not sure why the term shows up only if the requested order is more than one higher than `8/3`.  A bit counterintuitive, admittedly.

---

*Update:* In general, it appears that the series for

```
s = Series[Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, a/b, 1 - x], {x, 0, n}]
```

where $a$ and $b$ are integers and $a/b$ is not an integer, has the form

$$s = p_n(x) + x^{-2+{a \over b}}\,q_{n+1}(x)$$

where $p_n$ is a degree $n$ polynomial and $q_{n+1}$ is a polynomial of up to degree $n+1$, where the degree is truncated at either $n+1$ or $n+1+{a \over b}$, whichever is less.

This could be better in some cases, except the big-$O$ term is incorrect:

```
Series[
  Series[Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, a/b, 1 - x], {x, 0,Ceiling@Max@{n, n - a/b + 1}}], 
  {x, 0, n}]
```

For the OP's `a/b = -1/3` and `n = 3`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Seems also to happen for `Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, -1/n, 1 - x]`.

Comment: This is the error, $x^{8/3}$ should be presented if the order limit is set to $3$, the same for $11/3$ in a case of $n=4$.

Comment: @ahrvoje Yes, just so.  Please report it to WRI.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, use the [Pfaff transformation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E1):

```
Series[x^(-7/3) Hypergeometric2F1[-4/3, -4/3, -1/3, 1 - x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

which has the `-((64 π x^(8/3))/(2187 Sqrt[3]))` term that is missing from `Series[Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, -1/3, 1 - x], {x, 0, 3}]`.